# Load un-aligned time series into a DataFrame, with one index?

Tags: python, pandas

I am starting out learning this wonderful tool, and I am stuck at the simple task of loading several time series and aligning them with a "master" date vector.

For example: I have a csv file: Data.csv where the first row contains the headers `"Date1, Rate1, Date2, Rate2"` where Date1 is the dates of the Rate1 and Date2 are the dates of Rate2.

In this case, Rate2 has more observations (the start date is the same as Date1, but the end date is furhter apart then the end date in Date1, and there are less missing values), and everything should be indexed according to Date2.

What is the *preferred* way to get the following DataFrame? (or accomplishing something similar)

```
index(Date2) Rate1 Rate2
11/12/06     1.5   1.8
12/12/06     NaN   1.9
13/12/06     1.6   1.9
etc
etc
11/10/06     NaN   1.2
12/10/06     NaN   1.1
13/10/06     NaN   1.3
```

I have tried to follow the examples in the official pandas.pdf and Googling, but to no avail. (I even bought the Pre-Edition of Mr McKinney´s Pandas book, but the chapters concering Pandas where not ready yet :( )

Is there a nice recipe for this?

Thank you very much

**EDIT**: Concerning the answer of separating the series into two .CSV files:
But what if I have very many time series, e.g

Date1 Rate1 Date2 Rate2 ... DateN RateN

And all I know is that the dates should be almost the same, with exceptions coming from series that contain missing values (where there is no Date or Rate entry) (this would be an example of some financial economics time series, by the way)

Is the preferred way to load this dataset still to split every series into a separate .CSV?

**EDIT2** archlight is completely right, just doing "csv_read" will mess things up.

Essentially my question would then boil down to: how to **join** several unaligned time series, where each series has a date column, and column for the series itself (.CSV file exported from Excel)

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I don't think splitting up the data into multiple files is necessary. How about loading the file with `read_csv` and converting each date/rate pair into a separate time series? So your code would look like:

```
data = read_csv('foo.csv')

ts1 = Series(data['rate1'], index=data['date1'])
ts2 = Series(data['rate2'], index=data['date2'])
```

Now, to join then together and align the data in a DataFrame, you can do:

```
frame = DataFrame({'rate1': ts1, 'rate2': ts2})
```

This will form the union of the dates in `ts1` and `ts2` and align all of the data (inserting NA values where appropriate).

Or, if you have N time series, you could do:

```
all_series = {}
for i in range(N):
   all_series['rate%d' % i] = Series(data['rate%d' % i], index=data['date%d' % i])

frame = DataFrame(all_series)
```

This is a very common pattern in my experience

Comment: Thank you, but I encountered two problems here:

1) The Series isn´t recognized as a time series, is there a way to parse the index as dates?

2) The series´s (ts1 in this case, the slightly shorter series) index contains NaN´s .Since it´s read from a CSV file exported with excel, when the series "ends" the rest of the entries are just empty values. 

I tried ts1.dropna(), but this doesn´t only remove NaN at the _index_. (and I needed to remove all NaN before the _frame = DataFrame({'rate1': ts1, 'rate2': ts2})_ command would work)

I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I just wanted to make a quick note that I just updated to the latest Enthought distribution. This didn´t change anything. And if a quick glance at my data-set would help clarify my question; here´s a link to a representative sample of what my series look like (54 KB) 

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13846181/Data.csv

Thank you.

Comment: Anyone? Is my data-representation that uncommon?

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure that Date1 is subset of Date2 and Date2 contains no empty value, you can simply do

```
df = read_csv('foo.csv', index_col=2, parse_dates=True)
df = df[["rate1", "rate2"]]
```

but it will be complicated if Date2 has date which Date1 doesn't have. I suggest you put date/rate pair in separate files with date as common header

```
df1 = read_csv('foo1.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
df2 = read_csv('foo2.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
df1.join(df2, how="outer")
```

**EDIT:**
This method doesn't look good. so for your NaN in your datetime, you can do sth like

```
dateindex2 = map(lambda x: datetime(int("20"+x.split("/")[2]), int(x.split("/")[0]), int(x.split("/")[1])), filter(notnull, df['Date2'].values))
ts2 = Series(df["Rate2"].dropna(), index=dateindex2)
#same for ts1
df2 = DataFrame({"rate1":ts1, "rate2":ts2})
```

the thing is you have to make sure that there is case like date exists but not rate. because dropna() will shift records and mismatch with index

Comment: Dear archlight, thank you. But what if I have many Date/Rate series, is the convention still to separate them into several files? (I updated my main quesiton)